# Special values (NaN) are not being copied while saving as a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few text files which I am reading using `pd.read_csv` and then I am performing the following code to merge them

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_csv('\\cbh.txt', sep="\t")
    cbh = data['cbh'].to_frame()
    time = data['time'].to_frame()
    latitude = data['latitude'].to_frame()
    longitude = data['longitude'].to_frame()

    data1 = pd.read_csv('\\e.txt', sep="\t")
    e = data1['e'].to_frame()

    main1 = time.join(latitude)
    main2 = main1.join(longitude)
    main3 = main2.join(cbh)
    main4 = main3.join(e)
    print(main4)

    main4.to_csv(r'\\main.csv', header=True, index=False, mode='w', sep=',')
```

But while saving the file as a CSV the special values (NaN) are not stored

Following is the output when I print the merged data

```
      time   latitude  longitude           cbh         e
0    61359  23.459999  72.300003   7985.723352 -0.000256
1    61359  23.459999  72.425003   9758.239313 -0.000275
2    61359  23.459999  72.550003  11570.430130 -0.000307
3    61359  23.334999  72.300003   7914.476258 -0.000281
4    61359  23.334999  72.425003   9728.343473 -0.000313
5    61359  23.334999  72.550003  11562.327510 -0.000352
6    61359  23.209999  72.300003   7882.624615 -0.000320
7    61359  23.209999  72.425003   9718.564460 -0.000359
8    61359  23.209999  72.550003  11554.504300 -0.000398
9    61359  23.084999  72.300003   7871.169200 -0.000365
10   61359  23.084999  72.425003   9708.785447 -0.000404
11   61359  23.084999  72.550003  11546.401690 -0.000443
12   61359  22.959999  72.300003   7859.713785 -0.000397
13   61359  22.959999  72.425003   9699.006434 -0.000437
14   61359  22.959999  72.550003  11538.578480       NaN
```

Following is the file I get after saving it as a CSV

[image]

Comment: When exporting, add the "na_rep" parameter equal to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks it works fine

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is the absence of a value (number) in this case, and you save to `CSV` format it will simple be kept empty, with two separators next to each other: `,,`. If you read that file back into python using `pandas` you should have the same `NaN` values, however, if you open on `Excel` or other tool, it might just appear as blank.

Different tools display missing value in different ways.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was wondering thanks for clearing my doubt